# Hide a menu until a box is hovered

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have an accordion style menu that floats to the right of the page.  It takes up a lot of space and I would like to find a way to make it hidden.

How can I make an orange box to be put in its place and whenever hovered, the menu appears.

EXAMPLE:

[image]

My menu:  http://jsfiddle.net/4dHYq/

HTML:

```
<ul class="menu">
        <li class="item1"><a href="#">ABOUT US</a>
            <ul>
                <li class="subitem1"><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                <li class="subitem2"><a href="#">Strange “Stuff”</a></li>
                <li class="subitem3"><a href="#">Automatic Fails</a></li>
                <li class="subitem1"><a href="#">Cute Kittens</a></li>
                <li class="subitem2"><a href="#">Strange “Stuff”</a></li>
                <li class="subitem3"><a href="#">Automatic Fails</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="item2"><a href="#">ACADEMICS</a>
            <ul>
                <li class="subitem1"><a href="#">Cute Kittens</a></li>
                <li class="subitem2"><a href="#">Strange “Stuff”</a></li>
                <li class="subitem3"><a href="#">Automatic Fails</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="item3"><a href="#">RESOURCES</a>
            <ul>
                <li class="subitem1"><a href="#">Cute Kittens</a></li>
                <li class="subitem2"><a href="#">Strange “Stuff”</a></li>
                <li class="subitem3"><a href="#">Automatic Fails</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="item4"><a href="#">DEPARTMENTS</a>
            <ul>
                <li class="subitem1"><a href="#">Cute Kittens</a></li>
                <li class="subitem2"><a href="#">Strange “Stuff”</a></li>
                <li class="subitem3"><a href="#">Automatic Fails</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="item5"><a href="#">FAQs</a>
            <ul>
                <li class="subitem1"><a href="#">Cute Kittens</a></li>
                <li class="subitem2"><a href="#">Strange “Stuff”</a></li>
                <li class="subitem3"><a href="#">Automatic Fails</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    font-size: 100%;
    background:#cccccc;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
ul, ul ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
.menu {
    float: right;
    width: 300px;
    height: auto;
}
.menu > li > a {
    background-color: #f36f21;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #444;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2.75em;
    line-height: 2.75em;
    text-indent: 2.75em;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    color: #fff;
}
.menu ul li a {
    background: #fff;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #efeff0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 2em;
    line-height: 2em;
    text-indent: 2em;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    color: #444;
}
.menu ul li:last-child a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #444;
}
.menu > li > a:hover, .menu > li > a.active {
    background-color: #444;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #f36f21;
}
.menu > li > a.active {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #f36f21;
}
.menu > li > a:before {
    font-size: 36px;
    height: 1em;
    width: 1em;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 50%;
    margin: -.5em 0 0 0;
}

.menu > li > ul li a:before{
    content: '▶';
    font-size: 8px;
    color: #bcbcbf;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    top: 0;
    left: -2.7em;
}

.menu > li > ul li:hover a,
.menu > li > ul li:hover a span,
.menu > li > ul li:hover a:before {
    color: #444;
}
```

Comment: Um, you haven't asked a question.

Comment: Sorry about that.  Revised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply a generic hide class (display:none;) to your Menu UL with a Div. Inside this Div place a Span which will act as the access point to your menu.

You can then add the following code :

```
$('.menuAccess').hover(function () {
    $('.menu').removeClass('hide');
}, function () {
    $('.menu').addClass('hide');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/danieljordan13/Ha58r/2/

Answer (score 1):

```
    $('.menu').hide();
    $('#hm').hover(function(){
        $('.menu').show();
    },function(){
        $('.menu').hide();
    });
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/yR5gg/7/)